# Wordpress: how to show two posts per custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have some custom post types. I want to loop through three of them and only show two posts per each post type!

The following code works, it gets the posts I want, however if there are 4 posts in 'humour' and 2+ in 'crime', the query never gets to 'romance' posts

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => array('humour', 'crime', 'romance'), 'showposts' => 6);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I did think about creating three different new queries (using `WP_Query`), but I have a feeling that would be an overkill! Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`"numberposts" => 2,`

Comment: Not working! I read upon it, and also tried `posts_per_page` and nothing happens

Comment: Please try this: `$args = array( 'post_type' => array('humour', 'crime', 'romance'), 'numberposts' => 2);` . `posts_per_page` is for pagination.

Comment: yes it works, sorry I forgot that I  humour when I created the custom post, I used humor. Sorry, and thanks a lot